# Extracting a portion of a date from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, partitioning, substr

Basically want to drop the old partition(s) in an Oracle table, currently am having trouble with the SUBSTR function.

Code :

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
  l_date     DATE;

BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT * 
             FROM user_tab_partitions
             WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME')
  LOOP
    l_date := to_date( substr( x.high_value, 11, 19 ), 'YYYYMMDD' );
    IF( l_date < add_months( trunc(sysdate), -15 ) )
      THEN
        l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME' || ' DROP PARTITION ' || x.partition_name;
        dbms_output.put_line( l_sql_stmt );
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The date is present in the column "HIGH_VALUE".
For example one of the partition's High_value = `TO_DATE(' 1950-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')`

I need the date to be stored in "l_date" variable, so it can be used for further computations.

Error :

ORA-01843: not a valid month

ORA-06512: at line 9

01843.00000 -  "not a valid month"

Comment: What problems are you having? Does it run, and if so, what is the difference between the results and what you were expecting?

Comment: Are you getting "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string"? The substr argument and format model look wrong for a date partition; what raw high values are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `high_value` equals the following (which is what I think you're saying): `TO_DATE(' 1950-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')`, then the following line of code is wrong:

```
l_date := to_date( substr( x.high_value, 11, 19 ), 'YYYYMMDD' );
```

The reason that it is wrong is because the mask `YYYYMMDD` is wrong. `SUBSTR( x.high_value, 11, 19)` will return the following:

```
1950-01-01 00:00:00
```

So you want to use `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` as your mask:

```
l_date := to_date( substr( x.high_value, 11, 19 ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
```

or perhaps `SYYYY-MM-DD` (as in `high_value` itself), assuming that the year must be *signed*:

```
l_date := to_date( substr( x.high_value, 11, 19 ), 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' );
```

It might be worth your while to try and extract the mask from `high_value` (using, for example, a regex) and use that!

**UPDATE** This will work to capture the mask, assuming that `high_value` is of the same general format:

```
-- Try to capture the mask
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 'TO_DATE('' 1950-01-01 00:00:00'', ''SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'', ''NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'')' AS high_value
      FROM dual
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(x.high_value, '[^'']+', INSTR(x.high_value, '''', 1, 3))
  FROM x
```

So you might use the following in your code:

```
l_date := TO_DATE( SUBSTR( x.high_value, 11, 19 ), REGEXP_SUBSTR( x.high_value, '[^'']+', INSTR( x.high_value, '''', 1, 3 ) ) );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this response, thanks for the suggestion code, it worked the way i wanted.